# How to include examples or test programs in a package?

Tags: python, python-import, python-packaging

The [Python Cookbook](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920027072.do) suggests the following tree structure for a *"typical library package"*:

```
projectname/
    README.txt
    Doc/
        documentation.txt
    projectname/
        __init__.py
        foo.py
        bar.py
        utils/
            __init__.py
            spam.py
            grok.py
    examples/
        helloworld.py
```

You 'll notice that the `examples/` are not part of the actual package, which resides under `projectname/projectname/` (that's where you 'll find the top-level `__init__.py` of the package).

Well, `examples/helloworld.py` obviously needs to import the `projectname` package.

I am aware that there are at least 2-3 relevant questions in StackOverflow. I do not believe that this is a duplicate because the other questions either involve intra-package imports or the general case of importing one python module from another when they do not reside in the same directory. I am specifically asking for the suggested way to do this when packaging a library.

Is there a way to achieve this without modifying the path? If modifying the path is the only way, is there a way for this to be done in an elegant manner?

Let me elaborate on that last point. In [Repository Structure and Python](https://www.kennethreitz.org/essays/repository-structure-and-python) by Kenneth Reitz, a similar structure appears, with `tests/` instead of `examples/`. This is exactly the same problem. He suggests using *"a simple (but explicit) path modification to resolve the package properly."* OK, but this is the actual code:

```
import os
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('..'))
```

I really don't like the `..` part. I would hope for a more general solution, hopefully one that would work from whichever directory I would choose to run the example (or the test).

Comment: You mean other than using a relative path in an import or explicitly passing the module to import? If projectname is a package, you can always just explicitly import it after it's installed. In tests, this is usually what you do. Am I missing something in your question?

Comment: How would "using a relative path in an import or explicitly passing the module to import" work? What would be the import line for, say, ``examples/helloworld.py``? Because I haven't been able to make it work... As for the other suggestion, Kenneth Reitz also mentions "Expect the package to be installed in site-packages" as an alternative but argues against it.

Comment: I must be misunderstanding then. You want to import something from `examples`? If so, why isn't it a package?

Comment: ``examples/helloworld.py`` is an example of how to use the ``projectname`` package. So, ``examples/helloworld.py`` must import the ``projectname`` package. Unfortunately, a simple ``import projectname`` at the beginning of ``examples/helloworld.py`` will not work. Neither will relative imports, which, if I understand correctly, work only for imports _within_ a certain package. ``examples/helloworld.py`` is outside the package.

Comment: Well then, if the projectname package is installed, it means it's non-relatively importable (e.g. `import projectname`). This means that as long as the `helloworld.py` script/example runs in the context of the python environment where `projectname` is installed, it's also importable.

Comment: So, say someone comes across the code on github. And (s)he wants to try it out, run one of the examples like ``helloworld.py``. (S)he clones the repository and just wants to run ``helloworld.py``. Why should it be necessary to install the package? Also, the same goes for the developer. Why would I need to install the package every time I make a change? In the linked article by Reitz, it says: _"Requiring a developer to run ``setup.py develop`` to test an actively changing codebase also requires them to have an isolated environment setup for each instance of the codebase."_

Comment: And that is a very common thing to do. You use a virtualenv and install the package (using pip) in editable mode so that you can modify the code and execute it immediately without installing everytime. It's much cleaner and explicit than trying to import stuff. Let's move this to chat if you wanna discuss this further.

Comment: @nir0s: Thank you very much for the pointer. Got it: https://packaging.python.org/distributing/#working-in-development-mode

Comment: I'm posting the answer you asked for.

Comment: Adding an up to date link to #working-in-development-mode:  
https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/guides/distributing-packages-using-setuptools/#working-in-development-mode

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While the folder tree looks alright, I believe that implicitly assuming that modules are available for import is wrong from both a developer's perspective and certainly from a user's perspective.

It's true that you can technically use `sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('..'))` to add any path for python to allow imports from, but that means you, the developer, have to make sure that the added path is always in the right location.

It is common for users to install packages to use them. There's a clear workflow for developers:

1. Have pip and virtualenv installed (and even better, virtualenvwrapper)
2. Install the package in editable mode using pip's `-e` flag which means that any changes you make to the code will directly effect execution. You won't have to reinstall everytime you make changes to your code.
3. Since your code is always installed (specifically, under `site-packages` as a user but in editable mode when you develop), you can always import your package using its explicit name from any example or test.

A common workflow:

```
$ pip install virtualenv
...
$ virtualenv distro
New python executable in /home/nir0s/work/distro/bin/python3
Also creating executable in /home/nir0s/work/distro/bin/python
Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...done.

$ source distro/bin/activate

# install in editable mode
$ pip install -e ~/repos/nir0s/distro/
Obtaining file:///home/nir0s/repos/nir0s/distro
Installing collected packages: distro
  Running setup.py develop for distro
Successfully installed distro

(distro) $ pip freeze
appdirs==1.4.3
-e git+git@github.com:nir0s/distro@e8a182f9d1dbe6391f25...#egg=distro
packaging==16.8
pyparsing==2.2.0
six==1.10.0
```

The package, being installed in editable mode, means that there's an egg-link file pointing to the directory of the package:

```
$ cat distro/lib/python3.6/site-packages/distro.egg-link 
/home/nir0s/repos/nir0s/distro
```

Users will do the same thing without dealing with editable mode. Simply creating virtual environments and install packages in them. Then, when they're done working, they'll delete those virtual environments. Easy peasy.

Comment: This answer doesn't address the actual availability of the examples to the users who've installed the package. Are the examples part of the installation, or not? Do the users have to jump through hoops to locate the path to the examples?